# Client-server socket communication

Tags: android, sockets, stream

**Problem**

How to send **UTF-8** data between the server and the client, if I can use on client only

```
inputStream.read()
```

?

**Docs**

> Reads a single byte from this stream and returns it as an integer in
>   the range from 0 to 255. Returns -1 if the end of the stream has been
>   reached.

Without reader.readLine() and any another. (With reader I cant see end of stream)

Help please!

(full code:)

```
int c;
String str = new String();
while ((c = inputStream.read( )) != -1)
{
    char ch = (char)c;
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
        Log.v("", str);
        final String data = str;

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                String put[] = data.split("#");
                try
                {
                    //cmd parsing
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //stop connection
                }
            }
        });
        str = "";
    }else{
        str += Character.toString(ch);
    }
}
//Communication error
```

Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string) previous post.  There's a couple of good options on there.  The `read()` method can be overloaded with different parameters, so you can read one byte, or *n* bytes.  Check out the full documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).  Basically, you'll have to read in the raw bytes, then convert them to ASCII characters.  Also, I'm curious as to why you can't use `BufferedReader` or an equivalent class?

Comment: It seemed to me that BufferedReader returns null value not when the stream doesn't contain lines instead it comes to an end. I need to use letters from other alphabets therefore I use UTF8. Thanks for the good link.